# Oracle SQL Date Format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have been trying to convert the following varchar into date format with no luck:

```
12/99
01/04
```

I have tried to_char(mydate, 'mm/yy') which gives me errors.  Is there any way to convert this to date format even though I am missing the day?

Comment: So you have a DATE type, and you want to show the month,year only?

Comment: Yes, that is how it was entered in the Access db and I am trying to migrate the data to Oracle.  I tried the to_char(to_date(mydate, 'mm/yy')).  However some of the years are not correct, for example 99 ends up being 2099 instead of 1999.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use RR format for year:

```
select to_date('12/99','mm/rr') from dual --01/12/1999
select to_date('01/04','mm/rr') from dual --01/01/2004
```

This format get years between 1950 to 2049.

Comment: And when the current year is 2050, it will give you different results; 12/99 will give you December 1, 2099, and 01/04 will give you January 1, 2150.

Comment: If they're executing this same code in 2050, they'll have more serious problems then that.